# How do I configure email in contact form in Blogger?

Tags: xml, blogger, contact-form

I have created a custom contact form for a website in blogger.  When someone fills in their info an clicks submit I would like it to send an email to the one connected to the blogger account.  I am unsure how to make this step happen in blogger as I do not have access to the server for .php file.

If anyone can help me out with this I would be very thankful!

```
.question-button {
  color: #000;
  font-family: "Rubik";
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px 2.5%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.question-button em{
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
}

.float{
  position:fixed;
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  bottom:12px;
  right:7px;
  background-color:#41c230;
  color:#FFF;
  border-radius:50px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
.my-float{
  margin-top:18px;
}

.modal {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed; 
  padding-top: 15%;
  padding-left: 68%;
  z-index: 22;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: auto; 
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.message-box {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  max-width:400px;
  cursor: move;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {bottom:-300px; opacity:0} 
  to {bottom:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {bottom:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {bottom:0; opacity:1}
}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 13px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #41c230;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

<div class='question-button' id='question-button'>
<span>QUESTIONS?</span><br/><em>Send a message</em>
<a class='float'>
<i class='fa fa-comments my-float fa-2x'> </i> 
</a>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class='modal' id='mymodal'>

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js'/>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js'/>
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( &quot;#draggable&quot; ).draggable();
  } );
</script>

<div class='message-box' id='draggable' method='post' name='contact_form'> 

<span class='close'>X</span>

  <form>
    <input id='name' name='firstname' placeholder='Your name..' type='text'/>

    <input id='email' name='email' placeholder='Your email..' type='text'/>

    <textarea id='subject' name='subject' placeholder='Write your message here and click Submit' style='height:200px'/>

<img alt='Logo' src='' style='width:100%;max-width:150px'/>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
  </form>
</div>
</div>

<script>
var modal = document.getElementById(&quot;mymodal&quot;);
var btn = document.getElementById(&quot;question-button&quot;);
var span = document.getElementsByClassName(&quot;close&quot;)[0]; 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = &quot;block&quot;;
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = &quot;none&quot;;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a 'contact box widget' to the sidebar, hiding the contact box, and then just adding the code for the contact box into my modal.